# Squaring a Binomial

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to find ab if:

$$
a - b = 3
$$
$$
a^2 - b^2 = 21
$$

What I already know is the following:
To find ab for:

$$
a - b = 3
$$
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 29
$$

ab is:
$$
2ab = (a^2 + b^2) - (a - b)^2
$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. However I was not looking for explicit answers like what a is and what b is. I was just looking at what the equation is to find ab (here ab means a x b). As in the example above, 2ab = (a^2 + b^2) - (a-b)^2; this equals to 29-3^2 = 29 -9 = 20/2; so ab = 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b) = 21 \Rightarrow (a+b)\times 3 = 21
$$

Can you finish the calculation from here?

Answer (score 0):

From $a-b=3$ and $(a-b)(a+b)=21$ we get $a-b=3$ and $a+b=7$ and $a=5$, $b=2$.